# Setting up a docker registry on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, docker-registry

I want to set up a private registry on an AWS ec2 instance, in such a way that I could securely push images, and our clients could securely pull them (but not push).

Right now I tried to do so with a self-signed certificate but I'm really confused about how it's supposed to work, and how to separate the push of images by me and the pull by the customers.

It would really help me if someone that has done something like that before could elaborate on how he did this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try setting ECR. The push and pull can be controlled by assigning specific  IAM role. I am assuming the client also will be using EC2 instance to pull the request.